# yii 2 migration error after file deleted then run migrate/down

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I have created a file migration and run yii migrate.

After running I deleted a file migration.

 I got an error after run migrate/down.

Could anyone tell me how to resolve it ?

Comment: If you deleted the migration you obviously can't run `migrate/down` because there isn't any code to be executed..

Comment: i deleted name of file migration on table migration and it solved